# Alfresco community edition-5.1.x is possible to start workflow using custom javascript

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I have created custom advanced workflow in alfresco community edition-5.1.x ,i want to start workflow using custom javascript is possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar to this,

```
var workflow = actions.create("start-workflow");
workflow.parameters.workflowName = "activiti$<YOUR_WORKFLOW>";
workflow.parameters["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDescription"] = "test";
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowPriority"] = "2";
workflow.parameters["bpm:sendEMailNotifications"] = true;
workflow.parameters["initiator"] = people.getPerson("admin"); 
var today = new Date();
var duedate = today.getDate() + 1; 
workflow.parameters["bpm:workflowDueDate"] = duedate;
workflow.execute(document);
```

Comment: Ok Fine,Actually problem is i have create custom JS file in /opt/alfresco-community/tomcat/webapps/share/js/call_startworkflow.js, If i use the code this file i am getting error "ReferenceError: actions is not defined" , Can you tell me how i can use the code and where i need to place the code

Comment: This is a server side javascript and you need to execute them via Javascript (https://addons.alfresco.com/addons/javascript-console) . When you place under,  share/js/call_startworkflow.js, then it will be treated as client side javascript That's the reason, you're getting ReferenceError.

Comment: Could you please explain me how i can make it as server side javascript or else how to trigger server side javascript from client side javascript

Comment: From where , do you want to start the workflow ? Like document action or something like that? Please elaborate bit more.

Comment: I have workflow1 in workflow form i am using check box to start workflow once checked the check box start new workflow 2

Comment: i have written javascript for startworkflow i placed into /Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/triggerStartworkflow.js i create rule for the file is it trigging workflow , cloud help me how to trigger server javascript from client javascript please help me out

Answer (score 0):

You can create a ( java or javaScript ) Webscript that start the workflow and call it from a client JS.

Comment: please provide a reference for that

Comment: can you help can i call Webscript that start the workflow and call it from a client JS

Comment: check this [link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/workflow/how-start-workflow-using-java-02162009-0759) to create the webscript (mrogers's answer). And then call it from the JavaScript like the rjohnson's answer in this [link](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/alfresco-share-development/how-call-alfresco-java-webscript-share).

Comment: i have written javascript for startworkflow i placed into `/Company Home/Data Dictionary/Scripts/triggerStartworkflow.js` i create rule for the file is it trigging workflow , cloud help me how to trigger server javascript from client javascript please help me out

Answer (score 0):

js-api maybe can help you to start the workflow from a webscript: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api

```
 //Call a GET on a Web Scripts available at the following URIs:          http://127.0.01:8080/alfresco/service/mytasks

 this.alfrescoJsApi.webScript.executeWebScript('GET', 'mytasks').then(function (data) {
   console.log('Data received form http://127.0.01:8080/alfresco/service/mytasks' + data);    
}, function (error) {
   console.log('Error' + error);
});

//Call a GET on a Web Scripts available at the following URIs: http://127.0.01:8080/share/service/mytasks

this.alfrescoJsApi.webScript.executeWebScript('GET', 'mytasks', null, 'share').then(function (data) {
   console.log('Data received form http://127.0.01:8080/share/service/mytasks' + data);    
}, function (error) {
   console.log('Error' + error);
});

//Call a GET on a Web Scripts available at the following URIs: http://127.0.01:8080/share/differentServiceSlug/mytasks

this.alfrescoJsApi.webScript.executeWebScript('GET', 'mytasks', null, 'share', 'differentServiceSlug').then(function (data) {
   console.log('Data received form http://127.0.01:8080/share/differentServiceSlug/mytasks' + data);    
}, function (error) {
   console.log('Error' + error);
});
```